# Non-@objc property 'borderColor' is declared in extension of 'UIView' and cannot be overridden

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to update my ios's project from xcode 12.2 to 13.1, but i am getting the next error

```
Non-@objc property 'borderColor' is declared in extension of 'UIView' and cannot be overridden
```

When i execute this one in the version 12.2 xcode, it is not showing this error

The code is

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


open class MaterialTextField: UITextField {
    // MARK: - Tooltip
    fileprivate var isTipRaised = false

    @IBInspectable override var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            self.setColorAppearance(self.defaultColor)
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshot is

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where is it declared? Don't post screen shots. Please edit your question, post your code and its context.

Comment: Can you post the code as text as well as the screen-shot, and also include the code of the extension that defines `borderColor`?

Comment: @duncanC , i updated the code

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez - somewhere in your project you have (likely) `extension UIView` where `borderColor` is declared. You should be able to find it with Right-click on `borderColor` and select `Jump to Definition`.